# Determine the value of $f(x,y)$ on an arbitrary straight line through the origin.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Define $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$,  f is not defined in $(0,0)$.

Determine the value of $f(x,y)$ on an arbitrary straight line through the origin.

Also determine the limit of $f(x,y)$ when $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ through a straight line. We have to investigate all straight lines through $(0,0)$.

So far I just determined that the formula for the line is $y=cx$ with $c\in \Bbb R$.

Do I just fill this in in $f(x,y)$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by a "random straight line"? Do you want to restrict $f$ to a line? By "random" do you mean "arbitrary"?

Comment: I don't know the book just said determine the value of $f(x,y)$ on a arbitrary straight line through the origin

Comment: Ok, so just plugging in $y=cx$ should work.

Comment: But you also have to check the line $x=0$, as that isn't covered by the above family.

Answer (score 0):

First,note $y= c*x $ and you replace it in $f(x,y)$

$f(x,cx)=\frac{c²x^{3}}{x²+c^{4}x^{4}} $ when you apply the limit when $x$ approches $0$ , the limit is $0$ for all $c$ ∈ $\mathbb{R}$